# Adding Period to Single Letters, i.e., middle initial (If single letter, add period, if not leave normal)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a weird situation I am trying to work through.

[image]

I have a list of names in different formats. All I want to do is add a period to single letters because it is a middle initial.

I have tried:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)=1,A2&". ",IF(A2="","",A2&" "))
```

This works but misses instances with '&' and another name. So in A2, the result comes out to Michael F. & Jane J instead of Michael F. & Jane J.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A2)," &",". &")&".","..",".")
```

This ran into errors in instances with a single name and no middle initial or when there are no names in the cell or when there is a fill middle name.

[image]

Any suggestions? Text to columns also works. I can split them out and then run the above formula on all four columns then concatenate but it is an inefficient process.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2," &",". &")&".","..",".")
```

[image]

Edit :

If your source data have a space after the last period, try to add a trim() to remove the last space and the formula become >>

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A2)," &",". &")&".","..",".")
```

Comment: I am getting double periods on row 5. So the formula is posting Michael F. .

Comment: I can do a find and replace but is there a way to write this where if there is already a period it will not add another?

Comment: @Exalted_X, please see my post edit.

Comment: I added a picture above. I am running into errors. There should only be periods on single letters. Additionally, when there is no value, I do not want a period placed in the column. See on row 4, it added a period to the end of Steven. Then row 18, it added a period to Carroll.  Let me know your thoughts.